# JTabbedPane shows itself randomly

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jtabbedpane

the problem I encountered is weird for me, because I was doing everything step by step, correctly (in my opinion) and finally when I could say I finished one part of my program it appeared to make a fun of me. The actual problem is that in GUI I created I used a JPanel, then I've put it into a JTabbedPane which I've finally put into  a JFrame. Everything is fine and works apart from times when it doesn't. I know it sounds strange, but after running program once I get what I wanted (Frame with tabbed pane containing panel with some stuff in it) and then when I run it again it either show the correct thing again or just empty frame. The worst thing is that it's so random, I haven't got a clue what can be wrong, I don't even know what exactly should I google to find it out. The code is:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("WakeOnLan script generator");
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(null);
JTextArea text; //= new JTextArea("test");
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
JButton but = new JButton("test");
JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();

public GUI() {

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int w = frame.getSize().width;
    int h = frame.getSize().height;
    int x = (dim.width-w)/3;
    int y = (dim.height-h)/4;

    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLocation(x,y);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(null);

    createTab1();

    tab.addTab("Tab 1", panel1);
    tab.setVisible(true);
    tab.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);

    frame.add(tab);

}

public void createTab1(){

    text = new JTextArea("test");
    text.setVisible(true);

    scroll.setViewportView(text);
    scroll.setBounds(10,10,465,300);

    panel1.setLayout(null);
    panel1.add(scroll);
    panel1.setVisible(true);
    panel1.setSize(500,500);
    //panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }

   }
```

And then I just run it in the main method in other class:

```
public class GUIStarter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GUI start = new GUI();

}

}
```

So could anyone give me an answer or just a hint? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `frame.setVisible(true)` **after** adding all your components to your JFrame. So try moving it to the end of your constructor.

Alternatively, you can call `frame.validate()` after all the components have been added.